# Autodesk Tandem viewer React

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-tandem

I need some help on runnning the sample code of the Autodesk Tandem React viewer.
https://github.com/autodesk-tandem/tandem-viewer-react-2legged

I've managed to run both the server-side and client-side code, but the webpage returns a blank page with the error of :
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.DtApp is not a constructor.

I did check the App.tsx file, and there seem to be problems with the 'DtFacility' and 'DtApp'.

Namespace 'Autodesk.Viewing.Private' has no exported member 'DtFacility'.
Namespace 'Autodesk.Viewing.Private' has no exported member 'DtApp'

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you checkout [latest version](https://github.com/autodesk-tandem/tandem-viewer-react-2legged), pls? There were changes in the namespace recently and version on GitHub wasn't updated. The namespace is now **Autodesk.Tandem**.

Comment: Thanks lot, the latest version works.